# Updating MULTIPLE values in a column in pandas dataframe using ffill (or other methods)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that can be simplified like this:

```
TR = [17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]
Event = ['SRNeg', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 'Rating', np.NaN, np.NaN, 'ArrowTask', np.NaN]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event':Event,'TR':TR})
```

I want to fill in some NaNs after the `event` value with that value. Note that not all NaNs are filled. Here is the ideal output:

```
TR = [17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]
Event = ['SRNeg', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 'Rating', np.NaN, np.NaN, 'ArrowTask', np.NaN]
Event_BOLD_Duration = ['SRNeg', 'SRNeg', 'SRNeg', 'SRNeg', 'SRNeg', 'SRNeg', 'SRNeg', 'SRNeg', 'Rating', 'Rating', np.NaN, 'ArrowTask', 'ArrowTask']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event':Event,'Event_BOLD_Duration':Event_BOLD_Duration,'TR':TR})
```

Here is the code I have so far to complete the above task.

```
#line 1
scores_full['Event_BOLD_Duration'] = scores_full['Event'].where(scores_full['Event'].isin(['SRNeg', 'SINeg'])).ffill(limit=7).fillna(scores_full['Event']) 
#line 2
scores_full['Event_BOLD_Duration'] = scores_full['Event'].where(scores_full['Event'].isin(['ArrowTask'])).ffill(limit=4).fillna(scores_full['Event']) 
#line 3
scores_full['Event_BOLD_Duration'] = scores_full['Event'].where(scores_full['Event'].isin(['Rating'])).ffill(limit=1).fillna(scores_full['Event'])
```

However, each line seems to override the previous line's output. How can I fix this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create individual group with the common pattern **"<condition>.cumsum()"** then fill values on each group. To help us, create a dict of limits:

```
limits = {'SRNeg': 7, 'SINeg': 7, 'ArrowTask': 4, 'Rating': 1}

forward_fill = lambda x: x.ffill(limit=limits[x.iloc[0]]) \
                             if x.iloc[0] in limits else x

df['Event_BOLD_Duration'] = (
    df.groupby(df['Event'].notna().cumsum())['Event']
      .transform(forward_fill)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Event  TR Event_BOLD_Duration
0       SRNeg  17               SRNeg
1         NaN  18               SRNeg
2         NaN  19               SRNeg
3         NaN  20               SRNeg
4         NaN  21               SRNeg
5         NaN  22               SRNeg
6         NaN  23               SRNeg
7         NaN  24               SRNeg
8      Rating  25              Rating
9         NaN  26              Rating
10        NaN  27                 NaN
11  ArrowTask  28           ArrowTask
12        NaN  29           ArrowTask
```

Comment: Thank you!! I got a KeyError: nan when I applied this to my original dataset, and it seems to be coming from the transform `lambda` function. Any idea what might have gone wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `df['Event'].unique().tolist()` please? It seems NaN is a string and not the null value.

Comment: Here is the output: `[nan,
 'InstrSocial',
 'RecallSocial',
 'SocReframeNeg',
 'Rating',
 'ArrowTask',
 'SocImmerseNeut',
 'SocImmerseNeg',
 'InstrSelf',
 'RecallSelf',
 'SelfImmerseNeut',
 'SelfImmerseNeg',
 'SelfReframeNeg']`

Comment: If the key is not in the `limits` dict what should be the expected behavior? forward fill all values or fill nothing? I updated my code, can you try it?

Comment: It should follow the event key in `limits` dict that came before. E.g. The NaN right after `Rating` in `Events` is `Ratings` in `Event_BOLD_Duration`. However, if the NaN is not covered by any of the ffill for event key in `limits` dict, then the output should just be NaN in `Event_BOLD_Duration`

Comment: No it doesn't work as expected because I set `limit=None` if the key is not in `limits` so it fills all values with the first value. In my last approach, it left untouched the group if the key is not in `limits`. Which version do you prefer?

Comment: Apologies for the late response, I had to step out for a bit. 

Yes, the most updated solution works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df['Event_BOLD_Duration']=df['Event'].fillna(method='ffill')
df.loc[10,'Event_BOLD_Duration']=np.nan
print(df)
```

Output

```
    Event      TR   Event_BOLD_Duration
0   SRNeg       17  SRNeg
1   NaN         18  SRNeg
2   NaN         19  SRNeg
3   NaN         20  SRNeg
4   NaN         21  SRNeg
5   NaN         22  SRNeg
6   NaN         23  SRNeg
7   NaN         24  SRNeg
8   Rating      25  Rating
9   NaN         26  Rating
10  NaN         27  NaN
11  ArrowTask   28  ArrowTask
12  NaN         29  ArrowTask
```